# Loading data with ajax when open many tabs at the same time shows wrong data in tabs

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I write an application with C# MVC which is loading some data with AJAX request to a partial view with different IDs,

my problem is that if I click on two links(with ctrl to open in new tabs) at the same time, first tab load first link constant data but the partial view which load data by AJAX load the second link data!

is there anyway to solve this issue ?

Comment: Are you using something on the server that caches requests? Or maybe a shared data storage like Sessions?

Comment: No, I use sql server

Comment: Could you post the controller/partial view for us to review?

Comment: Sure, but I have many codes in them, let me make them simple and update my post tomorrow, thank you in advanced

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as  Andrés Nava comment on my Question I found that
The problem is that I use tempData to send some data between actions, I have changed my strategy and now it works well.